# Regular Expression: Currency Amount over 5,000,000

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
^((R|AED|AFN|ALL|AMD|ANG|AOA|ARS|AUD|AWG|AZN|BAM|BBD|BDT|BGN|BHD|BIF|BMD|BND|BOB|BRL|BSD|BTN|BWP|BYR|BZD|CAD|CDF|CHF|CLP|CNY|COP|CRC|CUC|CUP|CVE|CZK|DJF|DKK|DOP|DZD|EGP|ERN|ETB|EUR|FJD|FKP|GBP|GEL|GHS|GIP|GMD|GNF|GTQ|GYD|HKD|HNL|HRK|HTG|HUF|IDR|ILS|INR|IQD|IRR|ISK|JMD|JOD|JPY|KES|KGS|KHR|KMF|KPW|KRW|KWD|KYD|KZT|LAK|LBP|LKR|LRD|LSL|LYD|MAD|MDL|MGA|MKD|MMK|MNT|MOP|MRO|MUR|MVR|MWK|MXN|MYR|MZN|NAD|NGN|NIO|NOK|NPR|NZD|OMR|PAB|PEN|PGK|PHP|PKR|PLN|PYG|QAR|RON|RSD|RUB|RWF|SAR|SBD|SCR|SDG|SEK|SGD|SHP|SLL|SOS|SRD|SSP|STD|SYP|SZL|THB|TJS|TMT|TND|TOP|TRY|TTD|TWD|TZS|UAH|UGX|USD|UYU|UZS|VEF|VND|VUV|WST|XAF|XCD|XOF|XPF|YER|ZAR|ZMW) ?([1-9][0-9]{0,2}((,| )?[0-9]{3}){2,}|0)\.[0-9][0-9])?$
```

It will match on any Currency value 1,000,000 or greater.  I need it to match on 5,000,000 or greater. That seems like it should be a simple change but I'm struggling with it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `?([5-9][0-9]{0,2}((,| )?[0-9]{3}){2,}|0)\.[0-9][0-9])?`

Comment: This, unfortunately, I have already tried. It won't match 10,000,000. Actually, it won't match any number that starts with 1-4.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: You shouldn't do math with regex - match a number, parse it, and do an integer comparison. That said, http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html.

Comment: @Bergi I agree with you but I'm working within the constraint that I have to use a Regular Expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Description

`^(R|AED|AFN|ALL|AMD|ANG|AOA|ARS|AUD|AWG|AZN|BAM|BBD|BDT|BGN|BHD|BIF|BMD|BND|BOB|BRL|BSD|BTN|BWP|BYR|BZD|CAD|CDF|CHF|CLP|CNY|COP|CRC|CUC|CUP|CVE|CZK|DJF|DKK|DOP|DZD|EGP|ERN|ETB|EUR|FJD|FKP|GBP|GEL|GHS|GIP|GMD|GNF|GTQ|GYD|HKD|HNL|HRK|HTG|HUF|IDR|ILS|INR|IQD|IRR|ISK|JMD|JOD|JPY|KES|KGS|KHR|KMF|KPW|KRW|KWD|KYD|KZT|LAK|LBP|LKR|LRD|LSL|LYD|MAD|MDL|MGA|MKD|MMK|MNT|MOP|MRO|MUR|MVR|MWK|MXN|MYR|MZN|NAD|NGN|NIO|NOK|NPR|NZD|OMR|PAB|PEN|PGK|PHP|PKR|PLN|PYG|QAR|RON|RSD|RUB|RWF|SAR|SBD|SCR|SDG|SEK|SGD|SHP|SLL|SOS|SRD|SSP|STD|SYP|SZL|THB|TJS|TMT|TND|TOP|TRY|TTD|TWD|TZS|UAH|UGX|USD|UYU|UZS|VEF|VND|VUV|WST|XAF|XCD|XOF|XPF|YER|ZAR|ZMW)\s?([5-9][,\s][0-9]{3}[,\s]|[0-9]{2,3}[,\s][0-9]{3}[,\s]|[0-9]{1,3}[,\s](?:[0-9]{3}[,\s]){2,})
([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- match on 5,000,000 or greater

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/cS7aA5/1

**Sample text**

```
usd 5,000,000.00
usd 15,000,000.00
usd 15,000,000,000.00
usd 15,000,000,000,000.00
usd 5,000.00
usd 4,999,999.99
usd
```

**Sample Matches**

```
usd 5,000,000.00
usd 15,000,000.00
usd 15,000,000,000.00
usd 15,000,000,000,000.00
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    R                        'R'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
All the other money types
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ZMW                      'ZMW'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                           (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [5-9]                    any character of: '5' to '9'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\s]                    any character of: ',', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\s]                    any character of: ',', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 2
                             and 3 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\s]                    any character of: ',', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\s]                    any character of: ',', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{1,3}               any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1
                             and 3 times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [,\s]                    any character of: ',', whitespace (\n,
                             \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (at least 2
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [,\s]                    any character of: ',', whitespace (\n,
                               \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2,}                    end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{3}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]{2}                 any character of: '0' to '9' (2 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                           "line"
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Extra Credit

You can further improve your expression execution time by 66% by replacing the many currency alternations with a simple span tree. The above expression takes 1060 steps to complete on that sample text, whereas the following expression takes 324 steps to complete.

`^(A(?:ED|FN|LL|MD|NG|OA|RS|UD|WG|ZN)|B(?:AM|BD|DT|GN|HD|IF|MD|ND|OB|RL|SD|TN|WP|YR|ZD)|C(?:AD|DF|HF|LP|NY|OP|RC|UC|UP|VE|ZK)|D(?:JF|KK|OP|ZD)|E(?:GP|RN|TB|UR)|F(?:JD|KP)|G(?:BP|EL|HS|IP|MD|NF|TQ|YD)|H(?:KD|NL|RK|TG|UF)|I(?:DR|LS|NR|QD|RR|SK)|J(?:MD|OD|PY)|K(?:ES|GS|HR|MF|PW|RW|WD|YD|ZT)|L(?:AK|BP|KR|RD|SL|YD)|M(?:AD|DL|GA|KD|MK|NT|OP|RO|UR|VR|WK|XN|YR|ZN)|N(?:AD|GN|IO|OK|PR|ZD)|OMR|P(?:AB|EN|GK|HP|KR|LN|YG)|QAR|R(?:ON|SD|UB|WF)?|S(?:AR|BD|CR|DG|EK|GD|HP|LL|OS|RD|SP|TD|YP|ZL)|T(?:HB|JS|MT|ND|OP|RY|TD|WD|ZS)|U(?:AH|GX|SD|YU|ZS)|V(?:EF|ND|UV)|WST|X(?:AF|CD|OF|PF)|YER|Z(?:AR|MW))\s?([5-9][,\s][0-9]{3}[,\s]|[0-9]{2,3}[,\s][0-9]{3}[,\s]|[0-9]{1,3}[,\s](?:[0-9]{3}[,\s]){2,})([0-9]{3})\.([0-9]{2})$`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks!  This does it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex.

`^((R|AED|AFN|ALL|AMD|ANG|AOA|ARS|AUD|AWG|AZN|BAM|BBD|BDT|BGN|BHD|BIF|BMD|BND|BOB|BRL|BSD|BTN|BWP|BYR|BZD|CAD|CDF|CHF|CLP|CNY|COP|CRC|CUC|CUP|CVE|CZK|DJF|DKK|DOP|DZD|EGP|ERN|ETB|EUR|FJD|FKP|GBP|GEL|GHS|GIP|GMD|GNF|GTQ|GYD|HKD|HNL|HRK|HTG|HUF|IDR|ILS|INR|IQD|IRR|ISK|JMD|JOD|JPY|KES|KGS|KHR|KMF|KPW|KRW|KWD|KYD|KZT|LAK|LBP|LKR|LRD|LSL|LYD|MAD|MDL|MGA|MKD|MMK|MNT|MOP|MRO|MUR|MVR|MWK|MXN|MYR|MZN|NAD|NGN|NIO|NOK|NPR|NZD|OMR|PAB|PEN|PGK|PHP|PKR|PLN|PYG|QAR|RON|RSD|RUB|RWF|SAR|SBD|SCR|SDG|SEK|SGD|SHP|SLL|SOS|SRD|SSP|STD|SYP|SZL|THB|TJS|TMT|TND|TOP|TRY|TTD|TWD|TZS|UAH|UGX|USD|UYU|UZS|VEF|VND|VUV|WST|XAF|XCD|XOF|XPF|YER|ZAR|ZMW) ?(([1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[5-9])((,| )?[0-9]{3}){2,}|0)\.[0-9][0-9])?$`

Updated [link](https://regex101.com/r/uQ7eT0/3).

Comment: This is almost correct. It fails if the number goes over 99,999,999.

Comment: @AndrewCooper Updating.

Comment: @AndrewCooper Check now.

Answer (score 0):

### Use alternation with a quantifier

The segment of your regular expression that needs to be addressed are the character classes that match a range from 1 to 999:

`[1-9][0-9]{0,2}`

**Use the alternation token `|` in conjunction with an increase to the first argument of the quantifier `{}` to achieve a range from 5 to 999:**

[`([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/kX5kF4/1)

[image]

**Optional enhancements:**

For brevity, you may also like to modify the leading currency identifier set to a character class instead:

`(R|[A-Z]{3})`

Likewise, you can minimize the segment that matches the trailing two-digit decimal with a quantifier:

`\.[0-9]{2}`

**Putting it all together:**

[`((R|[A-Z]{3}) ?([5-9]|[1-9][0-9]{1,2})((,| )?[0-9]{3}){2,})\.[0-9]{2}`](https://regex101.com/r/lX2jQ7/1)

[image]

*Source: [Regexper.com](https://regexper.com/#((R%7C%5BA-Z%5D%7B3%7D)%20%3F(%5B5-9%5D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D)((%2C%7C%20)%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D)%7B2%2C%7D)%5C.%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D)*

Answer (score -1):

Keep your regex as it is.

```
preg_match($patter, $string, $out);
$amount = str_replace(",","", $out[2]);

If ($amount>=5000000){
    // code here
}
```